# Regular expression to join group of 5 digits

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract 10 digit phone numbers from string. In some cases the numbers are separated by space after 2 or 5 digits. How do I merge such numbers to get the final count of 10 digits?

```
mystr='(R) 98198 38466 (some Text) 9702977470'

import re
re.findall('\d+' , mystr)
```

Close, but not correct:

```
['98198', '38466', '9702977470']
```

Expected Results:

```
['9819838466', '9702977470']
```

I can write python code to concat '98198' and '38466', but I will like to know if regular expression can be used for this.

Comment: Try `\d{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{5}` for optional spaces after the 2nd or 5th digit.

Comment: @jasonharper can you post this comment as answer? Though the other answers are working, this is more readable and easy to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

credit goes to commenter jsonharper

```
\d{2} ?\d{3} ?\d{5}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could remove the non-digits first.

```
>>> mydigits = re.sub(r'\D', '', mystr)
>>> mydigits
'98198384669702977470'
>>> re.findall(r'.{10}', mydigits)
['9819838466', '9702977470']
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the separators are one character long, this would work.

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\d.?)+\d', mystr)
['98198 38466', '9702977470']
```

Of course, this includes the non-digit separators in the match. A regex `findall` can only return some number of slices of the input string. It cannot modify them.

These are easy to remove afterwards if that's a problem.

```
>>> [re.sub(r'\D', '', s) for s in _]
['9819838466', '9702977470']
```

Answer (score 1):

> In some cases numbers are separated by space after 2 or 5 digits.

You can use the regex:

[`\b(?:\d{2}\s?\d{3}|\d{5}\s)\d{5}\b`](https://regex101.com/r/cTgaBs/1)

For example, this regular expression will match all of these:

```
01 23456789
01234 56789
0123456789
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you can achieve it just by a regex pattern alone. May be just use a pattern to get 10+ digits and spaces and then clean out its spaces programmatically. The below pattern should work as long as you are sure of there being some text between the phone nos.
`[\d ]{10,}`